# Get name of current indice in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an application coded in PHP that pulls a particular set of data from a MySQL database based on the users username. I return the database information like so:

```
function getUserImages($user, $startat = 0) {
$con = openDBConnection();
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT name,id FROM `pictures` WHERE user=? LIMIT ?, 10");
$sql->bind_param("si", $user, $startat);
$sql->bind_result($picName, $picId);
$sql->execute();
$arr = array();
while($sql->fetch()) {
    $arr[$picId]=$picName;
}
return $arr;
}
```

Now assuming that the way I'm inserting into this array is correct, when I cycle through it with a `foreach` like this:

```
foreach($arr as $v) {
echo '<a href="/index.php?pid=' . $CURRENT_ARRAY_INDICE_NAME . '">'
echo '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="url/'. $v .'.png" alt="Captured Image"';
echo '</a>';
}
```

It should get all the data that I just inserted into it. My question is how to set the value of `$CURRENT_ARRAY_INDICE_NAME`.

Comment: maybe simple search how foreach() really works will help. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @RoyalBg yeah, I was actually staring right AT that particular page, and saw the answer, and completely ignored it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    // $k is the current indice
}
```

See the [docs](http://php.net//manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) Also, when using associative arrays, `$k` is the current key and `$v`.

Comment: Wow, I literally just read this answer in the PHP docs for foreach, and thought to myself, "eh, that's just for multidimensional arrays". I seriously need to get some sleep obviously.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your foreach to this

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
```

where $k is the key of the current indice of the array you are fetching.

More info on the PHP docs here : http://php.net//manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php